# Case statement inside IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a variable age to be used on my query like below:

```
Declare @age as int 11

Select * from people p where p.age = @age
```

but I want to show all the people between 10 and 13 when I put 0 on @age, so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Select * 
from people p 
where p.age in( case 
                     when @age = 0 
                          then 10, 11, 12, 13
                          else @age
                     end
              )
```

Can someone give me a light?

Comment: Instead of having a single `@age` parameter, why not have `@MinAge` and `@MaxAge`? This way you can always specify the same min/max for a single value, or a range, and your query doesn't need to jump through hoops to figure out what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a `CASE` statement, you can just switch your `WHERE` clause around a bit. This should return the same results:

```
Select * 
from people p 
where 
( 
    @age = 0 
    AND p.age IN (10, 11, 12, 13)
)
OR
(
    @age != 0 
    AND p.age = @age
)
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a case statement:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM people AS p 
WHERE (@age = 0 AND p.age BETWEEN 10 AND 13)
OR (@age <> 0 AND p.age = @age)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems easiest

It is also easy to modify if the business rules change.

```
declare @min int
declare @max int
declare @age int

set @age = 0

if (@age = 0)
begin
   SET @min = 10
   SET @max = 13
end
else
begin
   SET @min = @age
   SET @max = @age
end 

Select * 
from people p 
where age >= @min and age <= @max
```

Comment: If by "perfectly" you mean "doesn't parse" then yes it does!

Comment: Ok, @AaronBertrand I fixed the typo :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm leaving my comment though because I thought it was funny. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from people
where (age between 10 and 13 and @age=0) 
or (age = @age)
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to add the SELECT to your  IN() part

```
Select * 
from people p 
where p.age in (SELECT case 
                     when @age = 0 
                          then 10, 11, 12, 13
                          else @age
                     end
              )
```

Comment: not quite sure why this was down voted. anyone care to explain?  i know it aint the most elegant solution, but it fits with the sql OP had tried to use

Comment: Did you test it?  First thing I suggest when down voted is to test it.  (Your code is not even close to correct syntax or semantics).